# the js code works fine when I manually put it in Chrome dev console and run it but it gives an error when I run it from index.html with the src tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can guess I am a complete beginner. The page has a image carousel that has 2 buttons to move between diffrent images. When I test my website using Brackets live preview, I get this error.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') at showSlide (script.js:15:28) at script.js:24:5`

Here's my code

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    // Function to display the current slide
    function showSlide(n) {
        // Wrap around to the first slide if exceeding the number of slides
        slideIndex = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;

        // Hide all slides
        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Display the current slide
        slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    }

    // Function to navigate to the previous or next slide
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlide(slideIndex + n);
    }

    // Display the first slide
    showSlide(slideIndex);
```

the images are not even displaying because the js is not work now

Comment: can you post your HTML?  The error suggests that `document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")` is coming back as `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get the same error when `slides.length` is equal to 0.

Perhaps `var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");` is failing to get the elements in Brackets?

In that case:

- `slideIndex = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;` would be `0%0` which is `NaN`
- `for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)` would not go inside the curly braces
- `slides[slideIndex]` would be `slides[NaN]` which is `undefined`, so it has no `style` property, thus giving you the error